# List comprehension subsuite

Tags: python, list, printing

If I have a list like:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

How can I print the list and at the same time append a single 1  to the number 3 ?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think you want to do those at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time" ?

Comment: Maybe he wants two threads, one that prints the list, another that raises a TypeError simultaneously? The challenging part here is of course synchronizing the threads so one doesn't finish before the other does its important work, and I'd say the GIL makes that a very advanced question.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?  It seems like a valid question.

Comment: @Aptly-named commenter, if you hover over the downvote button you will see several appropriate reasons for downvoting this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
print [x if x != "3" else "1" + "3" for x in ["1","2","3"]]
```

Or this:

```
print [x if x != "3" else "3" + "1" for x in ["1","2","3"]]
```

Or this:

```
print [x if x != "3" else str(1+int("3")) for x in ["1","2","3"]]
```

It really depends on what you mean with "add a single 1 to the number 3".

Comment: or "4" depending on your interpretation, but +1

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear what does the OP mean with "add a single 1 to the number 3"

Comment: yeah) i think that it should be "4"))

Comment: I think "31" makes more sense than "3". String addition isn't commutative…

Comment: OK guys, I edited my answer to take into account all the different interpretations of such a badly-formulated question

Comment: Quote of the day: _"String addition isn't commutative"_

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to achieve this:

```
print [str(int(i) + 1) if i == '3' else i for i in ['1', '2', '3']]
>>> ['1', '2', '4']
```

?